# How can i change a button icon from a web link that is saved in my database?

Tags: java, netbeans

Ok the purpose of the app is that the icon in the button uses an image form a link that is stored in mysql. The query fetches the desired link using result set from my data base and is added dynamically to the button icon url.

```
 public void tbMoviesload(String id) {
        try {
            Statement s = Database.mycon().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE id = '" + id + "' ");
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(rs.getString("Link"));
                jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url.toString())));
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            

           
            if (rs.next()) {
                TitleField.setText(rs.getString("Title"));
                DirectorField.setText(rs.getString("Director"));
                WritersField.setText(rs.getString("Writers"));
                ReleaseDateField.setText(rs.getString("ReleaseDate"));
                RunningTimeField.setText(rs.getString("RunningTime"));
                RatedField.setText(rs.getString("Rated"));
                GenreField.setText(rs.getString("Genre"));
                CastField.setText(rs.getString("Cast"));
                
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

I expect that the icon changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it may be because web paged are cached and if the icon has the same name then the browser probably does not refresh the content.

Comment: The links are saved in my database so i want to use those links as the resource for my button icon

Comment: I'm assuming that "uses an image form a link " is from an link.... When you view the web page's source from the broser. ie. Right-click and select View Source you should see the buttons image source as in <img src = .... that should be able to be opened in a seperate web gage and you will see just the image of the icon. If not then the page is not being constructed with a valid image source.... or if it is then click on refresh - some broswers want Ctrl button down before you Refresh. You should see the button with the icon.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Comment: The pointer is looking for data that is not at the location where the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Im trying to fix that don't know how

Comment: You need a variable and have the data in the variable which the pointer points to. A pointer is looking to a piece of memory which is empty  ie. null.